# Google Translate button, disable some links

Tags: html, css

im doing a website for videogames news and updates.I have to add a translation option, so i decided to add google translate button, but it disables the links in the menu on the right side.Please help!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> GameDog | Video games info </title>
    
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
</head>

<body>
    <section class="page">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src = "gamedoglogo.png">
                <p> <b> GameDog </b> </p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="toggle"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="aboutme"><a href = "aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
                    <li id="news">
                        <a href = "news.html">News about ↓</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href = "fortnite.html">Fortnite</a></li>
                            <li> <a href = "rl.html">Rocket League</a></li>
                            <li> <a href = "lol.html">League of Legends</a></li>
                            <li> <a href = "cs.html">CS:GO</a></li>  
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="main"><a href = "main.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>

        <h1 class="topic"> Home Page </h1>

        <div class = "card-info">
            <h3> Hey Gamers, </h3>
            <br>
            <h4> welcome to the site. Here you can find the latest news about your favourite games. We provide information about the current updates, changes and improvements. Here, in the site, you can also find the patch notes for the last update of your favourite games. Explore by clicking the button below or the News section above.</h4>
        </div>

        <div class = "button">
            <a href = "news.html"> Explore </a>
        </div>

        <div class="social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="facebook%20white.png", id="facebook-main"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/_lachovalev_/"> <img src="Black-icon-Instagram-logo-transparent-PNG.png", id="instagram-main"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="Black-icon-Twitter-logo-transparent-PNG.png", id="twitter-main"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="translate-1">
            <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
                <span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                        pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,it,fr,ru,tr,bg', autoDisplay: false,
                        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
                        }, 'google_translate_element');
                    }
                    </script>
                    <script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
                </span>
        </div>
        
    </section>

    
    
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="main.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li> <a href="news.html"> News </a></li>
            <li> <a href="aboutme.html"> About me </a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="social-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="toppng.com-facebook-black-white-icon-facebook-face-book-png-facebook-icon-for-footer-473x473.png", id="facebook-menu"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/_lachovalev_/"> <img src="Black-icon-Instagram-logo-transparent-PNG.png", id = "instagram-menu"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="Black-icon-Twitter-logo-transparent-PNG.png", id="twitter-menu"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
    </div>
        
    <script>
        const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
        const page = document.querySelector('.page')
        
        menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                    menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
                                    page.classList.toggle('active')
                                    })
    </script>
    
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            var navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
            var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
            navbar.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
            menu.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
        })
        
    </script>
    
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ffd700;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:15.62vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    z-index:-5;
}

.menu.sticky{
    position:fixed;
}

.menu ul{
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu ul li{
    padding:1.04vh 1.04vw;
}

.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    font-size:4.5ch;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
    color:dimgray;
}

.translate-1{
    position:absolute;
    left:3vw;
    top:16vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}

.translate-2{
    position:absolute;
    left:3vw;
    top:76vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Here are some photos:
[this is the page with the translate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHCWD.png)
[this is the menu on the right, when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8bu.png)

The links in the menu, should become gray when u hover on them, but due to the google translate button, they don't. When i remove the google translate button, it works, so the problem is there.

JS for the menu is included in the html
And also, im really sorry for my bad formatting, im new to this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu has a negative `z-index` value, so it's just falling behind everything. Make it a positive value or remove it altogether and you're set. If you have a specific reason for using the `z-index` on the menu, then you'll need to add it to the other elements as well so they're layering correctly and the menu items are accessible.

SO's snippet doesn't seem to like the Google translate script so here's a fiddle that shows that it still works with the z-index property modified:

https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/hwo73b64/8/

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffd700;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 15.62vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  padding: 1.04vh 1.04vw;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4.5ch;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: dimgray;
}

.translate-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3vw;
  top: 16vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.translate-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3vw;
  top: 76vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> GameDog | Video games info </title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <section class="page">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="gamedoglogo.png">
        <p> <b> GameDog </b> </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="toggle"></div>
          </li>
          <li id="aboutme"><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
          <li id="news">
            <a href="news.html">News about ↓</a>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="fortnite.html">Fortnite</a></li>
              <li> <a href="rl.html">Rocket League</a></li>
              <li> <a href="lol.html">League of Legends</a></li>
              <li> <a href="cs.html">CS:GO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="main"><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <h1 class="topic"> Home Page </h1>

    <div class="card-info">
      <h3> Hey Gamers, </h3>
      <br>
      <h4> welcome to the site. Here you can find the latest news about your favourite games. We provide information about the current updates, changes and improvements. Here, in the site, you can also find the patch notes for the last update of your favourite
        games. Explore by clicking the button below or the News section above.</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <a href="news.html"> Explore </a>
    </div>

    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="facebook%20white.png" , id="facebook-main"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_lachovalev_/"> <img src="Black-icon-Instagram-logo-transparent-PNG.png" , id="instagram-main"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="Black-icon-Twitter-logo-transparent-PNG.png" , id="twitter-main"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="translate-1">
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
      <span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                        pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,it,fr,ru,tr,bg', autoDisplay: false,
                        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
                        }, 'google_translate_element');
                    }
                    </script>
                    <script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
                </span>
    </div>

  </section>



  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="main.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href="news.html"> News </a></li>
      <li> <a href="aboutme.html"> About me </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="social-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="toppng.com-facebook-black-white-icon-facebook-face-book-png-facebook-icon-for-footer-473x473.png" , id="facebook-menu"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/_lachovalev_/"> <img src="Black-icon-Instagram-logo-transparent-PNG.png" , id="instagram-menu"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/LachezarValev"> <img src="Black-icon-Twitter-logo-transparent-PNG.png" , id="twitter-menu"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
    const page = document.querySelector('.page')

    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
      page.classList.toggle('active')
    })
  </script>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      var navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
      var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      navbar.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
      menu.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
    })
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: ty so much, it helped me, you are a legend

Comment: @LachezarValev No problem. If you could mark the check as answered I'd appreciate it and you can ping me if you need any further assistance on this :)

Comment: when i open the menu now, it doesnt open smoothly. Any suggestions?(p.s. i type @ and then your name, but idk why it doesnt tag you, and also how to you mark a check as answered it is my first question in stackoverflow, so i need a bit of help)

Comment: @LachezarValev Do you have a live version of your site or can you put together a jsfiddle with all of the relevant code for the layout etc? I don't see any transitions in the CSS your provided and changing the z-index shouldn't affect anything unless you're transitioning with the z-index (which you really shouldn't IMO)  somewhere that I can't see.

Comment: @LachezarValev the @ thing is a little wonky sometimes but I got the notification :) The check mark is in the top left of the posted answer under the vote marker and arrows

Comment: How can i upload my images to the jsfiddle, cuz otherwise the site doesnt make sense

Comment: @LachezarValev you'd have to put them on Imgur or a similar service and link them that way, but I don't think the images are the issue. Is there any other CSS code you didn't include in your OP? You have scripts for what looks like a menu toggle and classes for it but no corresponding CSS so that could be why I'm not seeing what you're seeing.  If you look at your OP, you'll see the menu is already open and there's nothing to toggle it with.

Comment: um yea, i only pasted the css for the menu, ill link all of it in the jsfiddle and send you the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh9zb31d/1/ Here you go

Comment: i just saw, that in the jsfiddle it does it smoothly. Idk why tho, when i open it on my pc in my browser it does smth

Comment: @LachezarValev Could be a hardware or browser issue but one thing that jumps out at me is that you have a `.page` element that covers everything (including the side nav) because of it's `z-index` so I'd recommend adjusting that or making it closeable or flow better in your structure because from a user standpoint that's frustrating since you can't actually click your side menu with that page window on top of everything. I'd recommend going through and checking how you're laying things out with positioning and z-index because using too much of both can get overwhelming really fast.

Comment: well, the idea was that the .page element will imitate the body, and the .menu element will go behind it, cuz i cant put the menu behind the body. And the idea is that the menu is only visible when u click on the .toggle element, i mean it isn't supposed to be visible all the time, as you said. Ty tho, ill try to check my z-indexes and fix anything wrong